How to implement Spring Security Property / Field base Security?
I use Spring Boot and also the method security there. Now, however, I need to expand this authorization somewhat. A field-based security is to be installed. This means that one user may see / change a property of an entity, another user may only see it and another user may neither see nor change it.
Customizing every web service is extremely time-consuming. I think this is a common requirement and has certainly been used several times before. But I can't find an approach. What can I search for? Does anyone know of an example or instructions?
Here is a typical example of a web service:
@GetMapping("/{id}")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('role_admin','role_backenduser','role_seller','')")
public Customer findCustomerById(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {
    return customerController.findCustomerById(id);
}

Now I need to find a way to customize the return object to the permissions:
Admin User:
  return Customer {Lastname, Firstname, Birthday} '(Birthday Read/write)'

Backend User:
  return Customer {Lastname, Firstname, Birthday} '(Birthday Only Read)'

Seller User:
  return Customer {Lastname, Firstname} '(Property Birthday not shown or null)'


What do you mean time consuming, annotating an endpoint takes 2 seconds. What kind of approach did you expect?

I think you need to implement Attribute Base Access Control (ABAC). The attribute in your example is Birthday column. I used this model in our project. Can you use third party or you are following a method in spring context? I can help you in using third party

Third party can be possible. What did you use?

@Toerktumlare Annotating is not the problem. The problem is that there are hundreds of possible combinations of properties, which I would have to program each time, and each user would have to have their own rest services. Surely nobody does that. Or am I misunderstanding something?

@Burner You could implement it in your mapper (DB to API, API to DB). That is one place to do it.

@Burner I used jcasbin for attribute base access control(ABAC) and role base access control (RBAC). please check https://casbin.org/editor/. I can share more info about jcabin or even publish as a answer. jcasbin support type of access control like ABAC,RBAC,ACL and etc.
